# How to display the webform submission data in the below format in Views?

Tags: views, webforms

I want to display the webform submission data along with some other information in the below mentioned table format (like multiple rows for a particular column inside of a table).

Is it possible with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), or can anybody suggest a module, if there is such or any other way of getting it? I tried searching but found no module that meets my requirements.

[image]

Comment: Yes, with views you can organize your data in a format like a table.

Comment: I think that this specific question implies particular settings, but in order to display data from Webform can be used the module [Webform MySQL Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) using the indications located here about [displaying Webform submission data in Drupal Views](http://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/displaying-webform-submission-data-drupal-views) (Drupal 7)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [Webform MySQL Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) module.
2. Then navigate to web form, you will find separate tab MySQL views.
3. Generate one view form the same by navigating to that view.
4. When the view is generated, you will find this view under structure menu, under views section.
5. Then you can display it as you wanted to display, either in grid, unformatted list, tabular format, etc.

As your image seems colourful and in tabular format, you could use CSS classes for that, applying them under *Advance section*.